# Why am I having too many re-renders in my React.useEffect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still beginner using ReactJS and I'm not understanding a problem I'm having.

My `useEffect` is getting a list of data and after that I do a `filter`.

But when I save the data value of this filter, and with a `console.log()` I try to see the return value of my filter, there is an infinite loop of data saved being loaded and I don't understand why this is happening.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here's my code and it's more easy to understand what I mean:

And I put my code into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-dawn-63k3v4?file=/src/App.js)

[print of console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v791m.png)

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

import { getAccommodations } from "./data";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const center = [-27.592495455704718, -48.484572875610034];

  const mapRef = useRef();
  const [thing, setThing] = React.useState(0);
  const [accommodationData, setAccommodationData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      const response = getAccommodations();

      const _response = response.filter((accommodation) => {
        return mapRef.current.leafletElement
          .getBounds()
          .contains([accommodation.listing.lat, accommodation.listing.lng]);
      });

      setAccommodationData(_response);
    }
  }, [center, thing, accommodationData]);

  // I commented this line to avoid too many re-renders
  // console.log("accommodationData: ", accommodationData);

  return (
    <Map
      ref={mapRef}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}
      center={center}
      zoom={13}
      onmoveend={() => {
        setThing(thing + 1);
      }}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      {/* I'll add some <Markers> here with the accommodationData array */}
    </Map>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `accommodationData` is in the dependency array for `useEffect`, which means that operation will be invoked every time that value changes.  And `setAccommodationData` is called in the operation, which will change that value.  What is the intent there?

Comment: I'd like to update this array whenever someone changes the map, be it zoom or position.

Comment: But why is `accommodationData` in the dependency array for `useEffect`?  If you remove that, what happens?

Comment: As I have `setAccommodationData`, I thought it was mandatory to put `accommodationData`, I did the test and remove `accommodationData`, it continued the same.

Comment: Leave only `thing` in the deps array of the effect. `center` is a variabe that is created ex novo at each render since you are declaring inside the body of the component, so it always retriggers the effect. You don't need it as a dep, and you should always declare static variables outside of the body of components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *useEffect* hook keep trigger because you are changing the state *accommodationData* which is one of the dependencies of *useEffect*. So you have just to remove it from dependencies or add another state *response* and then change *accommodationData* when you have a *response*, example :

```
  const center = [-27.592495455704718, -48.484572875610034];

  const mapRef = useRef();
  const [thing, setThing] = React.useState(0);
  const [accommodationData, setAccommodationData] = React.useState([]);
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current && !response) {
      const response = getAccommodations();

      const _response = response.filter((accommodation) => {
        return mapRef.current.leafletElement
          .getBounds()
          .contains([accommodation.listing.lat, accommodation.listing.lng]);
      });

      setResponse(_response);
    }
  }, [center, thing, accommodationData]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response) setAccommodationData(_response);
  }, [response]);
```

Comment: If you were using Eslint it would complain since you are adding unnecessary deps to the first effect.

Comment: I supposed he isn't using Eslint because he didn't mention it ;)